# One-Way operations vs Asynchronous calls

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

As stated in the [first section of this article](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/a/7/3a7fa450-1f33-41f7-9e6d-3aa95b5a6aea/MSDNMagazineOctober2006en-us.chm) (.chm file - see note below)

> One-way calls do not equate to asynchronous calls. When one-way calls
>   reach the service, they may not be dispatched all at once and may be
>   queued up on the service side to be dispatched one at a time... If the
>   number of queued messages has exceeded the queue's capacity, then the
>   client will block, even when issuing a one-way call.

If a one-way call is invoked, when does it return control to the caller? The introduction of the same article states that *one-way calls* are used *for fire-and-forget operations*, thereby simulating a kind of asynchronous call.
If a sessionful WCF service has a Login() one-way method which starts the session, when does this method return control to the caller? Does it return before the method is actually executed on the service? If so, how can I be sure that the method was performed on service?

If I wanted the service to return to the client the possible errors that occur during the login procedure, would be an asynchronous call the only way to achieve a fire-and-forget behaviour?

---

Note: The quote above is taken from an article called *WCF Essentials - What You Need To Know About One-Way Calls, Callbacks, And Events* by Juval Lowy, and can be found in the October 2006 issue of MSDN magazine. The link above is to a help file (.chm) format on MSDN. If you can't get the linked CHM file to work (I couldn't) you can open it with 7zip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If a sessionful WCF service has a Login one-way method which starts
>   the session, when does this method return control to the caller?

For OneWay calls: The caller will continue to execute as soon as the service call is dispatched or queued. Basically as soon as the service successfully receives the call.

> how can I be sure that the method was performed on service?

If the client does not get an exception, the service call was (or will be) performed. When the service call actual runs or whether it succeeded or threw an exception is unknown to the client.

> If I wanted the service to return to the client the possible errors
>   that occur during the login procedure, would be an asynchronous call
>   the only way to achieve a fire-and-forget behaviour?

This does not make sense. Fire-and-forget by definition means forget the result. It does *not* return any values or errors to the client. However an asynchronous call is not fire-and-forget and would return errors.

Comment: Just curious, "For OneWay calls: The caller will continue to execute as soon as the service call is dispatched or queued. Basically as soon as the service successfully receives the call."  Does this apply when service not found? Say we send a One way call to the Service, but the Service was actually down, will the Client execution still continue?

Comment: @KingChan, no this is not "basically as soon as the service successfully receives the call". It is as soon as as the service actually begins to execute the call, which could be much later if the server's queue is backed up. If the service was not found the one-way call would fail quickly on the thread that made the call.

Comment: If the service is not found, then there is nothing to "receive it" and the client will get an exception.

Comment: @Kit - Programing WCF Services by Juval Lowy 3rd Edition p226: "If the number of messages exceeds the buffer's capacity, the client will be blocked even if it has issued a one-way call. However, once the call is deposited in the buffer, the client will be unblocked and can continue executing while the service processes the operation in the background." In this context "deposited to the buffer" does not equal "exectue the call".

Comment: I see, so there still a handshake between the service. Thanks! +1

Comment: @ErnieL, _If the number of messages exceeds the buffer's capacity, the client will be blocked even if it has issued a one-way call_. How to prevent the client blocks in this situation?

Comment: @Enzom83 - How to prevent the client blocks in this situation? (last comment): In this situation the client will block. You prevent the situation from ever happening by increasing the service buffer size (see any of the WCF Throttling posts) or have the client make the call from a thread that it doesn't mind being blocked.